# GCM API version for http based GCM request

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

At present we are using http based GCM request from our server to push notification to Android phones. As we know there are two flavors of GCM apis for server push calls 1. HTTP based api 2. XMPP based api. I tried hard to find out version of http based GCM APIs however i was unsuccessful with it. Can anyone help me understanding current api version for GCM api [http based].

Comment: This is a very vague question. Are you asking about client side implementation of GCM or server side? If server side, what language are you using in your server?

Comment: I am sorry but i have clearly mentioned 'http based GCM request from our server to push notification to Android'. I assume that means server side api. We are using Java at server side

Comment: OK, so are you asking how to implement the server side? That would depend on the language you are using at your server side.

Comment: i want to know current http based GCM api version [server side] since it is hard to find this information on google's site.

Comment: What do you mean by "GCM api version [server side]"?

Comment: I believe every API [exposed by third parties like google/others] have versions associated with it. I checked their site/googled however was unable find such information. What if they do EOL of http API and just keep XMPP based APIs.

Comment: They might decide to deprecate the GCM HTTP API, as they did with the older C2DM, but currently they don't mention it anywhere. Both HTTP and XMPP are described in the docs as valid choices for GCM server side implementation. How would having a version change the fact the any API can be deprecated?